# Edit view SSMS Alter to

Tags: view, edit, ssms, alter

In the SSMS 2012 there is no option to edit view. When I choose design, SSMS offer some sort of smart designer which replaces my script with something else. As a work around I saw suggestion "Script View As" -> "ALTER to" -> "New Query Window". But I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Suppose I have a View_A that I would like to edit. If I try "Alter to" options, after editing it offers me to save to file. This effectively creates some SQL script in the file, but how do I let SSMS know that it should use this new script in the file for View_A.

I am either missing something simple or something fundamental.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Saving the file won't apply the changes. You need to execute the ALTER script on your database. There is a button in the button bar to do this, or you can use F5.